# facing problem with thunder api in vs code updated

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

[here i want to make a database named inotebook and and collection named authentication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seCN4.png)I am using react + mongoose + mongodb scale + express and i have already established my connection with the mongo db compass but now i want to create a database and collection through thunder client into the mongo db compass. I was watching the tutorial from youtube and did every steps the same but it doesnt work like that its not creating the database [here i did the requried to do solve my problem but its not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSw79.png)

i was trying to make a database named inotebook and collection named authentication i did make the database and the collection in the thunder client but i didnt work as it was supposed to even when i have connected my mongo db with it

Comment: what is your problem collection is not created or what?

Comment: Add the code as well giving only error report nobody gonna answer it